# How to improve query performance in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-1.4, symfony-1.2

The below query is taking too much time to load data. Is there anything wrong? What can i improve in here?

The below function is fetching all users records with some joins between date range input by user.

```
public static function getUsers($search_params) {
        $criteria = new Criteria();

        $criteria->clearSelectColumns();
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.id as id");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.drid as drid");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.name as name");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.email as email");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.active as active");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.lead_from as lead_from");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.source as source");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.http_referer as http_referer");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.sms_status as sms_status");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.telefon as telefon");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.datain as datain");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.kall as kall");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.ip_address as ip_address");

        $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(btq_user_track_blog_video.counter) as total_video_viewed");

        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.id as dr_id");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drname as dr_name");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drphone as dr_phone");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.initials as dr_initials");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_doctors.drmail as dr_mail");

        $criteria->addSelectColumn("event_data.btq_user_id as event_user_id");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=2, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_video_viewed");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=1, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_blog_viewed");

        $criteria->addSelectColumn("state.pres as pres");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("state.state as state");

        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.type as choice_type");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.opt_value as choice_value");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user_sales_choice.opt_text as choice_text");
        //$criteria->addSelectColumn("btq_user.pfu_customer_id as pfu_customer_id");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("lead_schedule.id as schedule_id");
        $criteria->addSelectColumn("lead_schedule.created_at as schedule_date");

        $criteria->addJoin(self::STATE_ID, StatePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
        $criteria->addJoin(self::BTQ_USER_SALES_CHOICE_ID, BtqUserSalesChoicePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
        $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, LeadSchedulePeer::LEAD_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
        $criteria->addJoin(self::DRID, BtqDoctorsPeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
        $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, BtqUserTrackBlogVideoPeer::USER_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);

        $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, EventDataPeer::BTQ_USER_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);

        $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::IS_DUMMY_DETAIL, "1", Criteria::NOT_EQUAL);

        $criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::DATAIN);
        $criteria->addGroupByColumn(self::EMAIL);

          if (!empty($search_params)) {
          foreach ($search_params as $key => $param) {

            if (trim($param)) {
              $param = addslashes($param);

              switch ($key) {

                case 'name':
                  $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::NAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
                  break;

                case 'email':
                  $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::EMAIL, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
                  break;

                case 'dr_name':
                  $criteria->add(BtqDoctorsPeer::DRNAME, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
                  break;

                case 'phone':
                  $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::TELEFON, "%" . $param . "%", Criteria::LIKE);
                  break;

                case 'lead_from':
                  $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::LEAD_FROM, $param, Criteria::EQUAL);
                  break;

                case 'start_date':
                  $criteria->add(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param, Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL);
                  break;

                case 'end_date':
                  $criteria->addAnd(BtqUserPeer::DATAIN, $param, Criteria::LESS_EQUAL);
                  break;

                case 'location':
                  if ($param == "Local")
                    $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::IN);
                  else if ($param == "Non Local")
                    $criteria->add(StatePeer::PRES, array("MD", "VA", "DC"), Criteria::NOT_IN);
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return $criteria;
      }
```

RAW QUERY:

```
$startdate = $searchParams['start_date'];
       $enddate = $searchParams['end_date'];
          $connection = Propel::getConnection();
          $query = "SELECT btq_user.id as id, btq_user.drid as drid, btq_user.name as name, btq_user.email as email, btq_user.active as active,
                   btq_user.lead_from as lead_from, btq_user.source as source, btq_user.http_referer as http_referer, btq_user.sms_status as sms_status,
                    btq_user.telefon as telefon, btq_user.datain as datain, btq_user.kall as kall, btq_user.ip_address as ip_address,
                     count(btq_user_track_blog_video.counter) as total_video_viewed, btq_doctors.id as dr_id, btq_doctors.drname as dr_name,
                      btq_doctors.drphone as dr_phone, btq_doctors.initials as dr_initials, btq_doctors.drmail as dr_mail, event_data.btq_user_id as event_user_id,   
                      count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=2, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_video_viewed, 
                      count(if(event_data.event_parent_id=1, event_data.event_parent_id, null)) as kms_total_blog_viewed,
                       state.pres as pres, state.state as state, btq_user_sales_choice.type as choice_type, 
                       btq_user_sales_choice.opt_value as choice_value, btq_user_sales_choice.opt_text as choice_text, lead_schedule.id as schedule_id,
                        lead_schedule.created_at as schedule_date FROM `btq_user`
                         LEFT JOIN state ON (btq_user.STATE_ID=state.ID) 
                         LEFT JOIN btq_user_sales_choice ON (btq_user.BTQ_USER_SALES_CHOICE_ID=btq_user_sales_choice.ID)
                          LEFT JOIN lead_schedule ON (btq_user.ID=lead_schedule.LEAD_ID)
                           LEFT JOIN btq_doctors ON (btq_user.DRID=btq_doctors.ID) 
                           LEFT JOIN btq_user_track_blog_video ON (btq_user.ID=btq_user_track_blog_video.USER_ID)
                            LEFT JOIN event_data ON (btq_user.ID=event_data.BTQ_USER_ID)
                             WHERE btq_user.IS_DUMMY_DETAIL<>1 AND (btq_user.DATAIN>='$startdate' AND btq_user.DATAIN<='$enddate')
                             GROUP BY btq_user.EMAIL ORDER BY btq_user.DATAIN DESC LIMIT 20
                  ";
```

The above is raw query. `$startdate` and `$enddate` variables are input by users it can start from 2000 to today's date. I hope my question is clear. If there is any confusion just let me know I will update my question. If any other data is required just comment and I will share it quickly. Let see where it goes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't worry about performance when it looks at first sight like you are using `GROUP BY` basically [wrong in MySQL](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) and you can and will get invalid data unless MySQL could have used [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct data.

Comment: Why is it wrong @RaymondNijland can you please ellaborate?

Comment: non aggregated columns used in the select clause should also be used the group by clause that is the ANSI SQL way..MySQL has extended that feature which allowes non aggregated columns which are in the select does not have to be in the group by clause the problem is you can get invalid data for every non aggregated column used in the select which is not used in the group by

Comment: You can check what's wrong by using raw sql + explain... Basically you could optimize speed with using indexes...

Comment: You have a LOT of joins, about how many rows is the result when you run this query for various date ranges?